# How to completely reinstall linux

Tags: reinstall

I was wandering if there is a way i could possibly due to **factory reset** Linux?
If someone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I would delete the partitions associated with Ubuntu (be careful), then run the setup utility again. Or you could just run the utility and choose to override your current installation.

Comment: On the installer, click "Something Else", then click the partition associated with Ubuntu (ext 3/4), and click use as ext 3/4 journaling file system (or something like that), and click mount to /, and check format.